# Is This Bike Worth 7K

Tags: price

I'd appreciate it if someone should take a look at this bike:

http://www.wheelyscafe.com/wheelys2.html

I realize they are selling more than just a bike. But does 7K seem reasonable?

EDIT

I'm not associated with the product. I'm thinking about investing in it.

Maybe a better, more specific question would be:

What questions should I ask them to know if the bike itself is of good quality?

[image]

Comment: Not to me - too slow up the hills. But nice to stop anywhere I like for a coffee :-)

Comment: Easy @andy256, didn't you see it comes with gears???

Comment: @PeteH Lol. I hope Brad doesn't think we are being rude.

Comment: @Brad Are you associated with the company that produces these marvels? If so, you should declare that. If not, then the value to you can really only be determined by you. Which is why, all fun aside, questions such as this are off topic.

Comment: Looks like a bargain compared with $33000 for  http://jamaica-gleaner.com/gleaner/20120826/business/business1.html
http://www.onyourtrike.co.uk/coffee-trike/ is  £10,999 but (IMHO) better looking.
The Wheelys apparently launched for $3000, but it looks as if it's been developed since: http://www.treehugger.com/bikes/coffee-cart-cargo-bike.html
If the price includes a franchise, not just the bike, then whether the business is worthwhile really is off topic, and will depend very much where you are anyway.

Comment: It has an electric assist as well as gears. Somewhere hilly, it probably needs it.

Comment: Yeah, you really have to think about something like this as a business investment. Coffee is very high markup.  You can make a cup of coffee for about 20 cents, and then sell it for $2.  So you'd only have to sell about 4000 cups of coffee to make your money back.  That's 40 cups a day (which isn't even a lot of coffee to sell) over 100 days.  I'm not sure what the franchise is like, or how much their cost on coffee actually works out to, but it seems like a relatively cheap way to start a business.

Comment: link dead 1/13/17 PAC local time Los Angeles

Answer (score 1):

I personally would say yes, if you're running a business that is. With all those feautures there's a lot that comes into play (not just the end product). Its pretty much a moving shop. So yeah $7000 is a hefty investment but if you were serious and knew what you were doing you could make that back quite easily :)